# NSOperation and the Autorelease pool

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I created an NSOperation.  Do I also need to create an autorelease pool for this or is it all handled for me like voodoo black magic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NSOperation may run on any thread, so yes, you must set up your own autorelease pool for the work being done.

Comment: With ARC, this is no longer true.

Answer (score 2):

You do need to create autorelease pool yourself in the `NSOperation` main method, if the environment doesn't support automatic garbage collection.

Comment: Wait... what?  Never should the words "autorelease pool" and "automatic garbage collection" appear in the same sentence. The two are completely different.  This makes no sense.

Comment: You just put them in one sentence ;-).  When running in the garbage collection mode, you don't need the autorelease pool; and if you aren't running in garbage collection mode, then you need to manage your own memory, possibly by using autorelease pools.  What doesn't make sense about this?